# WebApi controller dependencies cannot be resolved using StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently using StructureMap with MVC, but its complaining that my api controllers don't have a default constructor. Can someone point me in the right direction in order to set this up with StructureMap? As I understand, MVC and WebApi have separate resolvers (which makes sense since they are separate frameworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it for AutoFac [here](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-4-dependency.html). Should give you enough pointers to implement it yourself.

Comment: thanks, I also found this resource here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver